# Ctrl + Alt + S on Ubuntu 18.04 triggers a screen size toggle but is not listed in keyboard settings

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I want to allocate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to a shortcut in my IDE, however ubuntu uses this shortcut and it is not defined in the list under keyboard. Where do I set this shortcut?

Comment: Since this is the first result when searching for `linux "ctrl alt s"`, for anyone for whom the solutions below do not work: If you are using fcitx, check in the "Global Config" of the fcitx settings, for me `CTRL ALT S` was bound there to something. Removing the shortcut there solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have found that since Ubuntu 16.04 `Keyboard Bindings` mostly doesn't show the windows management shortcuts (though occasionally it does, and I've never worked out what controls it).

However, I can check and modify them with `dconf` or the GUI version `dconf-editor`.  Using this I see that `['<Control><Alt>s']` (lower case) is assigned to `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/toggle-shaded`: this is not the default entry, though I didn't set it explicitly.

You can change the entry to a different shortcut (eg `['<Shift><Control><Alt>s']` or restore the default setting by deleting it completely (`[]`).

If this isn't the entry in your case, then you can use `gsettings` to find other locations of the shortcut:-

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep -i \>s\'
```

This will find all shortcuts using the <kbd>s</kbd> key (plus a few spurious entries, perhaps - note that you can't be sure of the ordering of `<Control>`, `<Shift>` and `<Alt>` within the setting).

Comment: I checked dconf already and it does not have a value set for 'toggle-shaded', i.e. []. So how do I find out what is connected to ctrl+alt+s...?

Comment: You could try `gsettings list-recursively | grep -i \>s\'` (you can't be sure of the ordering of `<Control>`, `<Shift>` and `<Alt>`).

Comment: Yeah, cool! This is the cause: 
```org.gnome.shell.extensions.screenshot-window-sizer cycle-screenshot-sizes-backward ['<Shift><Alt><Control>s']
org.gnome.shell.extensions.screenshot-window-sizer cycle-screenshot-sizes ['<Alt><Control>s']```
Could you add the reg to the answer, then I can approve! Thanks!

Comment: @musicformellons the answer solves the problem, you can accept it as is. No? :)

Answer (score 2):

Reading [@AFH's correct answer](https://superuser.com/a/1352067/167207), I could not understand just what do do, so here:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-shaded
```

This will turn off this setting.

Answer (score 0):

A few years later, in 2024, Ubuntu 23.10, and the issue is still there ... (I'm trying to access IntelliJ's settings with <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>).

At least here `gsettings list-recursively | grep -i \>s\'` won't list anything.

I'm assuming because the updated Gnome Shell extension `screenshot window sizer` has it hard-coded. But disabling the extension solves the issue. I'm not sure why it was installed -- maybe I installed it years ago and forgot.

Just in case I created an [issue in Gnome Shell Extensions package](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell-extensions/-/issues/479).